# Primitive data type reference

Tags: java

I would like to make function that could return several primitive data types to caller.

I know I can return function result for first primitive, but how to return primitive in function param?

```
public boolean myFunc( boolean outAnotherPrimitive)
{
outAnotherPrimitive = true; //need to return value to caller
return true;
}
```

Is it only way to return primitive to wrap it into Object like Integer or Boolean?

Comment: _return several primitive data types_ Do you mean you want to have an object that has many primitive type fields?

Comment: You want to return the parameter as well?

Comment: Can you add some sample input and output of the function?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, wrapping it in an object like `Boolean` won't work; if you declare `Boolean anotherPrimitive` as the parameter, you can't assign anything to `anotherPrimitive` (and have the caller see the new value) because `Boolean` objects are immutable.

Comment: seems like tuple. you can copy (e.g. get inspiration) from [the way](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/tuple/TupleImpl.java) Storm does it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it only way to return primitive to wrap it into Object like Integer or Boolean?

Not at all,

I think its not good practice  to convert your variables to Object and after fetch them back with cast or `instanceof`.

- you can use **Interface as callback**.

example:

**OtherClass**

```
 public class OtherClass{

....

public void myFunc( boolean anotherPrimitive, MyinterfaceItf myItf)
{
 boolean bool = false;
 int a = 1; 
  myItf.onFinish(bool, a)
}
....
}
```

**MyClass:**

```
public class MyClass implements MyinterfaceItf {

 ....

 private void foo()
 {
    MyinterfaceItf itf = this;

    myFunc(true, itf );
 }

 @override
 public void onFinish(bool, a){
   // here you can get your primitive data 
 }

}
```

**interface**

```
public interface MyinterfaceItf{
 public void onFinish(bool, a);
}
```

- Other option to use variables as **global**

example:

```
private boolean bool = false;
private int num = 0;


public boolean myFunc( boolean anotherPrimitive)
{
 bool = anotherPrimitive;
 num = 10;
 //....
}
```

- Next option to create new Class and use it instead primitives.

example:

```
public class NewClass{
 private boolean bool = false;
 private int num = 0;
 //...

 public void setBool(boolean flag){
     this.bool = flag;
  }
}

 public boolean myFunc( boolean anotherPrimitive, NewClass newClass)
 {
   return newClass.setBool(true);
  }
```

*(I wrote it in local editor, sorry for syntax)*

Comment: its good,but he can use other approaches :) like write to file and read it, write to queque/dequeue, directly to memory :), BTW, your variant is better and easier, but question is so ..., he wants to use input parameters like ref in .NET, oh :(((